# SQL how to specify the int(size) when creating a table column?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table for a MS SQL database for the first time.
My query looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
);
```

I looked up on how to create a table and found a resource about SQL Data Types at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) here. It states that I can define a size after an integer, but it throws the following error:

Column ProductID has an invalid data type.
The UNSIGNED Keyword also is marked as having "Incorrect Syntax near 'UNSIGNED'".

I proceeded to google and search on here for this exact error but wasn't able to find an answer quickly which is weird as this seems like a pretty common error?

Removing the size attribute from the integer works, but I want to define the column width.

I tried to create a table in a MS SQL Database and the query throws errors as explained in the details.

Comment: `int` has a fixed size - 32bits. If you want a 4-digit integer use `numeric(4,0)`

Comment: Are you sure this is sql-server? I guess, based on the AUTO_INCREMENT, it is not.

Comment: The entire line is invalid. There's no `int(4)`, no `AUTO_INCREMENT` and no `UNSIGNED`. Did you try to use a tutorial for some other database? In SQL Server an auto-generated ID field would be `ID INT IDENTITY` or `ID BIGINT IDENTITY`

Comment: I suggest you use the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) for SQL Server types. There is no unsigned 32-bit integer type. You could specify `ProductID INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server.

Comment: This seems to be MySQL, not SQL-Server. Set the tag accordingly. You cannot set the size of an `INT`: See [Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) and [Numeric Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html).

Answer (score 2):

In MSSQL you have different types of INT:

- bigint   -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1
  (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)  8 Bytes
- int  -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)    4 Bytes
- smallint -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)  2 Bytes
- tinyint  0 to 255    1 Byte

If you want to have a larger one than INT, use BIGINT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks Peter, I figured that I used the wrong documentation. @dan-guzman provided the correct solution to this problem. Beginner mistake and I should have had my eyes open at looking for information material on SQL Server! It can get confusing when starting out. I appreciate everyones help!